# Windows 10 RDP and Network Share Mounting Stopped Working

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, network-shares

I recently upgraded to Windows 10. Even before the upgrade, RDP stopped working, and after the upgrade, mounting network shares worked, but then stopped working all of a sudden.

I have rebooted multiple times, and everything is enabled that has always been enabled on this same computer where these things were working for years.

RDP is listening on 3389.  When I try to RDP, I get an authentication popup, but it always fails with an authentication error message.  This happens when trying to login to a local account (which has always worked in the past) as well as a domain account, which should also work (but still fails).  Any ideas?

Edit:  I am not using insider preview, just stock Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE OBVIOUS-NOT-OBVIOUS FIX: Install latest drivers and patches from Windows Update**
This was a company computer, and we only have access to very specific updates on-network, probably distributed via Active Directory by WSUS.  This laptop usually functions like a desktop, hooked up to dual monitors, so I never move it, but I took it home with me and connected it to my home network and installed all of the latest patches and drivers.  After that, I had no issues with RDP.

**For those of you who found this question/answer who ARE running Windows Insider Preview:**
I also had *another* computer experiencing this *same issue* that was running the latest version of Windows Insider Preview (not sure which build), and RDP had broken on that computer as well *(unrelated to initial computer/issue/question)*.

I ended up having to reinstall stock Windows 10 in order to resolve that particular issue, because apparently the Insider Preview build had broken that functionality.  Heads up -- when going back to stock Windows 10 from Insider Preview, you don't get to keep your files, so make sure you're backed up.  Some of you may say that was a silly thing to do, and no in that particular case, that was not finding the root cause (but this wasn't the initial question).  However, that computer was also very important for VPN access from home to work, so I chose the swiftest method of attack, as I knew I would need to RDP to and from that box in the very near future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some 3rd party firewall has blocked 3389 even 3389 is listening. Try to telnet 3389, or change the RDP port 3389 (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber)?

Answer (score 0):

After the last W10P patch-tuesday I couldn't login to my RDP. When home again checked if it had to do with the router but no, locally it didn't work either. Then checked the settings. RDP was allowed as usual. I turned it off (saved) and on again. It seems to work for now.

When trying to login, I tried to reboot remotely. This wasn't allowed because the pc "was already in a shutdown process" (never ending...) When checking logged-in users remotely it said my Microsoft account was logged in. Kind of strange as I almost never use it and at startup my local account is selected to enter the password.

This might also be instructive: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2477176